# How to add primary keys which can report 1062 error?

Tags: mysql

Firstly, I used Navicat to cancel three primary keys in a table, and then I want to  recover the primary keys but I got `1062 - Duplicate entry '1539669761000-6708-200809260001' for key 'PRIMARY'`. I don't dare to do any operation now, because there are too much data. How can I do to recover the primary keys now?

This is the statement I used.

```
ALTER TABLE `pm_raw_p_reshost`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`DCTIME`, `KBP`, `KPI_NO`) USING BTREE;
```

[image: This] is the primary key this table had.

Will this work?

```
LOCK TABLES pm_raw_p_reshost;

ALTER TABLE `pm_raw_p_reshost`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`DCTIME`, `KBP`, `KPI_NO`) USING BTREE;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A PRIMARY KEY is also a UNIQUE KEY, so the problem is that the combination of fields: **`DCTIME`, `KBP`, `KPI_NO`** already have more than one unique rows which fails the creation of the PRIMARY KEY.

Possible solutions:

1. Remove the duplicates and re-create the PK, select the rows, decide which ones to keep.

   ```
   SELECT * from pm_raw_p_reshost where `DCTIME`=1539669761000 and `KBP`=6708 and `KPI_NO`=200809260001
   ```
2. Create a new table with the desired PK and use INSERT IGNORE to the new table, duplicate values will automatically be removed.